# C# generic casting exception

Tags: c#, .net, casting, generics

I have run into an odd casting issue while using generics. The following code will throw an `InvalidCastException` even though clearly an `int` can be cast to a `double`. Can anyone explain this behaviour and how to bypass it?

```
public class TestClass<T>
{
    public T Cast(object o)
    {
        return (T)o;
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    TestClass<double> w = new TestClass<double>();
    double x = w.Cast(10);
}
```

**Edit:**

Since I am in .net 4.0 land anyway I have changed it to use 'dynamic' instead of 'object' and everything works as expected. Appreciate all the spot-on and quick replies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**But an `object` can't be cast to a `double`.** The `o` parameter takes an `object`, not an `int`.

For example, the following code fails with an `InvalidCastException`:

```
 object o = 1000;
 double x = (double)o;
```

Comment: Nitpick: An `object` *can* be cast to a `double` if that `object` is a boxed `double`.

Comment: Indeed it can. That's not the case in the sample code, so I didn't think to include it, but it's certainly worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for that, clearly I wasn't thinking about the boxing to object.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) to convert variables

```
        public class TestClass<T>
        {
            public T Cast(object o)
            {
                TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(o);
                if (converter.CanConvertTo(typeof(T)))
                {
                   var result = converter.ConvertTo(o, typeof(T));
                   return (T)result;
                }

                throw new InvalidCastException(
                      string.Format("Cannot convert from {0} to {1}", o.GetType().Name, typeof(T).Name));
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks, I wasn't thinking clearly about the boxing. I appreciate your reply but have to give the points to the first poster...

Answer (score 1):

The parameter 'o' in Cast is boxed. You can't cast a boxed int to an unboxed double, apparently. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

If you'd known it was an int inside the Cast function you could do:

```
return (double)((int)o);
```

I don't know about the case of an unknown type. Checking.

EDIT: change T to double

Comment: Hmm, no. That code won't compile when inserted into the `Cast` function exactly as shown. You can't convert `int` to `T`.

Comment: Cody, well, yeah. I was just trying to show that in theory if o was unboxed into an int, the conversion would have worked. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

This would work

```
        object y = 10;
        Double v = (int) y;
```

this will not

```
        object y = 10;
        Double v = y;
```

because it has to be casted explicitly.

Comment: thanks, I wasn't thinking clearly about the boxing. I appreciate your reply but have to give the points to the first poster...

Answer (score 0):

You could bypass it by doing:

```
public class TestClass<T>
{
    public T Cast<T2>(T2 o)
    {
        return (T)o;
    }
}
```

Which should hopefully (no chance to test here) infer that you're using an int and allow the case. Although it doesn't prevent you putting other things that can't be cast properly in.

Comment: This will fail at compile-time because casting an arbitrary `T2` to an arbitrary `T` isn't possible.

Comment: Why would you *hope* for a runtime error? Catching the mistake at compile time seems like a much better option for all parties.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public T Cast(object o)
 {
     return (T)Convert.ChangeType(o, typeof (T));

 }
```

I am not sure why though.

Comment: The reason is that this method just wraps a call to the appropriate `IConvertible` method. It will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the type doesn't implement the `IConvertible` interface.

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing it's because an int can't be *casted* to a double, but there is an *explicit conversion* to a double. Which has to be defined on a type. As your Cast object doesn't know whether a given type will have this conversion it tries a basic cast and fails.